# Run exe file with parameters in a batch file

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Please have a look at my batch file.

```
echo off
start "c:\program files\php\php.exe D:\mydocs\mp\index.php param1 param2"
```

but it isn't working. Any ideas how do I get it working?

Answer (score 41):

This should work:

```
start "" "c:\program files\php\php.exe" D:\mydocs\mp\index.php param1 param2
```

The `start` command interprets the first argument as a window title if it contains spaces. In this case, that means `start` considers your whole argument a title and sees no command. Passing `""` (an empty title) as the first argument to `start` fixes the problem.

Comment: Ok great. I just tried that and it seems to work. Is there any way to capture the output or error? thx

Comment: It just seems to flash command panel for a quick moment ... could I keep that open so that i could see the output?

Comment: pause doesn't keep the window opened it just tells me to press any key to continue after that window has closed.

Comment: Yep, I forgot you're using `start` to open a second window.

Comment: Do you really need `start`?

Comment: Thanks to this i managed to make it work. I share my example: `start "" "c:\programmi\microsoft office\office14\outlook.exe" /safe` - i put this in autostart so that my outllok starts in safe mode since it has some issues

Answer (score 11):

If you need to see the output of the execute, use `CALL` together with or instead of `START`.

Example:

`CALL "C:\Program Files\Certain Directory\file.exe" -param
PAUSE`

This will run the file.exe and print back whatever it outputs, in the same command window. Remember the `PAUSE` after the call or else the window may close instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's just a simplified example for the question, my advice is that drop the batch wrapper and schedule PHP directly, more specifically the `php-win.exe` program, which won't open unnecessary windows.

```
Program: c:\program files\php\php-win.exe
Arguments: D:\mydocs\mp\index.php param1 param2
```

Otherwise, just quote stuff as Andrew points out.

---

In older versions of Windows, you should be able to put everything in the single "Run" text box (as long as you quote everything that has spaces):

```
"c:\program files\php\php-win.exe" D:\mydocs\mp\index.php param1 param2
```

Comment: actually I tried to create a schedule task but I keep getting error 0x1 in Last Run column but If I run the same command as above manually in the Cmd prompt it runs!! thats why I was thinking that perhaps it would work in a batch file??

Comment: also, the above is the exact lines of code as in my batch file (only added dummy param1 param2)

Comment: It isn't a script. Those are the fields you have to fill in the Task Scheduler interface.