# Using batch file to control dos user input

Tags: batch-file, input, dos

I'm using a program called lewice that runs in a dos window.
When you run the program it requires 'user input' to give a file name for the input files.

Is there anyway I can get a batch file to send the commands to the dos window so the batch file can by default use file name x?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain it more detail? Did you tried to make the batch script before?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you want but maybe lewice can use inputs parameters, you just have to create a shortcut and add options:

https://superuser.com/questions/29569/how-to-add-command-line-options-to-shortcut

It might get trickier if the path to the file has spaces.

Comment: I've managed to figure out how to get lewice to use input parameters thanks.

I wanted to edit the input file, i.e. line 4 is 

' LWC    =     0.530000000000000 '

so I want to change .53 to something else, how do I open a file and edit an individual line?

Comment: If you're talking about the input files with the name you provided in the shorcut, I guess you can use windows' classical notepad or download notepad++. Does that answer your question ?
Also, maybe a .bat file might be more powerfull than just a shortcut, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112377/run-exe-file-with-parameters-in-a-batch-file