# How to run visual studio exe from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My script is as below:

```
for %%i in (*.mudp) do echo %%i >> test.txt
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%i In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%i="

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (test.txt) DO SET $%%i=Y
(FOR  /F "delims=$=" %%i In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO ECHO %%i)>test.txt

 for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" ^< test.txt') do set Count=%%C
  echo The file has %Count% lines.
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\gbyraiah\pcap\createPcap\Debug"
start createPcap.exe %Count% 
exit
```

I am listing all text files with `.mudp` extension in the current directory to a `test.txt` file in Windows.

Then counting the number of files in the list and so I get `Count` value of `2` if 2 `.mudp` files are found.

Then I want to open Visual Studio `.exe`, loop the `.exe` to run it the number of times equal to `Count` and also pass count as a command line argument to the exe.

So here my issue is I am not able to run the `.exe` and so neither I am able to loop.

Comment: The exe for visual studio is 'devenv'. So to launch visual studio you could do `start devenv`. How did you tried to call it? What exactly do you want to do? It's not really clear

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My exe is located in the following path:-  C:\Users\gbyraiah\pcap\createPcap\Debug                        so i assumed i should write the following code to open the exe                                @echo off

cd "C:\Users\gbyraiah\pcap\createPcap\Debug"

start createPcap.exe %Count% 

exit

Comment: I initially misunderstood the question, you should edit it (not related at all to visual studio)
You should search for how to start an exe in bat.
that could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112377/run-exe-file-with-parameters-in-a-batch-file

Comment: Its a visual studio exe , i want to run visual studio application exe using batch file.

Comment: Okay my question is ,How to start visual studio exe with integer parameter as command line argument  from batch file .

Comment: okay i was able to run visual studio exe with command line argument passed as int with  the following command   So now my natch script works! and runs the visual studio exe .                                             @echo off
cd "C:\Users\gbyraiah\pcap\createPcap\Debug"
start "" "C:\Users\gbyraiah\pcap\createPcap\Debug\createPcap.exe" C:\Users\gbyraiah\pcap\createPcap\Debug

\createPcap.exe %Count%
exit

Comment: Thanks Haim Bendanan ! your suggestions helped!

Answer (score 0):

Simply write `yourExecutable.exe` to start it; write `yourExecutable.exe 1` to pass over the argument `1`.

To do that in a loop using arguments from `1` up to the value of `%Count%`, do this:

```
for /L %%J in (1,1,%Count%) do yourExecutable.exe %%J
```

---

The [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) should not be necessary for running your `.exe` at all. Regard that `start` runs the `.exe` in a new process, so the batch script does not wait for the `.exe` to be finished, unless you provide the switch `/WAIT` (like `start "" /WAIT yourExecutable.exe`; `""` is the title of a new window that might be opened, which should always be specified to avoid trouble with quotation of paths).